# Problem after anchor build

Tags: anchor, rust

I initialize a fully new project with "anchor init my-proj" and then I run the "anchor build". I have this error message related to stack:

Error: Function *ZN14solana_program4vote5state9VoteState11deserialize17he6c620cee6656e35E Stack offset of 6344 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 2248 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function *ZN229*$LT$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5..*..$LT$impl$u20$serde..de..Deserialize$u20$for$u20$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5..VoteState0_23_5$GT$..deserialize..__Visitor$u20$as$u20$serde..de..Visitor$GT$9visit_seq17h321a2adcad9bb5dfE Stack offset of 5752 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 1656 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

I have no clue what is the problem. Do you have any idea?
thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Anchor 0.26. It won't actually stop your project from being built so you should just ignore it.